# ansible command: module returning error

Tags: rhel, ansible

trying to do an iptables-save with ansible

```
name: Save Netfilter Rules

action: command  iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

But this gives error

```
failed: [10.110.211.17] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["iptables-save", ">", "/etc/sysconfig/iptables"], "delta": "0:00:00.009345", "end": "2014-06-09 16:55:18.306375", "rc": 1, "start": "2014-06-09 16:55:18.297030"}

stderr: Unknown arguments found on commandline
```

But over ssh this works fine:

```
ssh root@host "iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables"
```

works fine but not through Ansible command: module

How can i make this work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use the `shell` module for redirections, i.e.

```
...
name: Save Netfilter Rules
shell:  iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

See here [ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/command_module.html):